# How to log out of a website that sends back a page to verify if I want to log out using php and curl

Tags: php, http, curl, https

I am trying to logout of a website using curl. When clicked on the logout button this websites sends back a page that asks if we want to log out with two buttons "ok" and "cancel". I used curl to get this data

```
$headers = array(
    "GET $geturl HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: " . "$ip",
    "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0(X11;Linuxx86_64;rv:45.0)Gecko/20100101Firefox/45.0",        
    "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*,q=0.8",
    "Referer: " . $referer,
    "Cookie: JSESSIONID=" . $session_id,
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Length: 64",
    '"etag": W/"102-1257495352000"',
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); //timeout after 15 seconds  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, $session_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "logout=logout");
$result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
```

The output contains two forms:

```
            <form name="myLogout" action="logout.jsp" target="main" method="post">
                <input name="logout" type="hidden" value="logout">
                <input class="yesno" class="button" type="Submit" value=" OK ">
            </form>
        </td>
        <td width="20"></td>
        <td>
            <form action="start.jsp" target="main">
                <input class="yesno" type="Submit" value=" Cancel ">
            </form>
```

Then the session waits around 15 seconds to get a response for a post-event to the "OK" button. 
Thus I am sending another post request with the same curl options as above except I changed CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST from "GET" to "POST", But I am getting either null or "Bad Request". 
Can someone please help with this.

Comment: Why do you want to log out?  Just leave... lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix This function is automated to run on the ui every 15 minutes, but if we dont log out after 10-15 repetetions it says "Too many users logged in." and then it blocks everyone from the network. Thus i need to logout of this after I am done with scrubbing the data.

Comment: Are you sure that is the reason, where is this being saved between requests `$session_id` It's not in your code.  If you don't save this between requests then you have to login every time.

Comment: This is just a part of the scrub I am doing, what exactly happens here is first we login to the ui when logged in I save the session id. Then I am using that session id to navigate to other pages in the ui to get data. Then I want to log out of the ui as this session stays on for a very long time on the interface, thus after some repetitions, it just does not allow logins. I think your code works. After trying to scrub the data almost 20 times in a row I am able to login to it. Thank you for being so descriptive @ArtisticPhoenix  this was really helpful.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help.  I've done a ton of scraping over the years, everything from website rankings, to lawsuit, to recovering old sites from the wayback machine.

Answer (score 2):

Here I will do what i can to explain this.

All you have to do to submit that form or any form is to emulate what it is doing.

Ok, what do forms do?
Simply, they send a request to the server using one of 2 methods, GET or POST. GET is the same as using a URL in the browser (which is why when you submit it the query parameters change in the url and you get a new page).

So in theory you just make a `POST` request to `logout.jsp` the forms action with the data in the form `logout=logout`.

Think in terms of if you built that form

```
<form name="myLogout" action="logout.jsp" target="main" method="post">
    <input name="logout" type="hidden" value="logout">
    <input class="yesno" class="button" type="Submit" value=" OK ">
</form>
```

If I built this form, I would build a page at `action="logout.jsp"` I would be using the `$_POST` array, etc.(lets assume its PHP)

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
       session_destroy();
       header('Location: www.example.com');
       exti();
   }else{
      //some error message or redirect to 404, this should never happen.
      //maybe send message to the Internet police with your IP, just kidding
   }
```

So I would just look for the logout in the post array, then destroy the session, then redirect to my homepage.

So in curl you just need to

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, $session_id);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '{www.example.com}/logout.jsp');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'logout=logout');
```

And then the other standard CURL stuff.

Some things to consider:
Now this may or may not work, there are a lot of variable that I just don't know about to be able to say it will 100%.  They can do things with cookies and JavaScript that is beyond what you can do with just CURL (eg. PhantomJS or headless browser scrappers).  However, this HTML is pretty simple (eg. no random generated IDs) so I think it's not that advanced.

One thing to do, is in a browser, go to that page when logged in.  Press `f12` open the browser debug window.  Find the network panel, find the record button (or persist).  Logout, then inspect the request that was made to the server for that form.  This is what you need to replicate.

In conclusion I done to much scrapping over the years.  Now we have a `.Net` guy to handle it.  It's a bit better suited to what we needed then PHP.